# C# - what is this code doing and what's it called?

Tags: c#

I came across this piece of source code and I've never seen C# code like this before.

Can someone tell me what it's doing and where I can read more about the technique ?

```
<%= Foo.Bar()
        .DoSomething(1)
        .DoSomething(2)
        .DoSomething(3)
        .DoSomethingElse("Apples")
%>
```

(EDIT: As some answers have mentioned this:  I'm not interested in the signicance of the angle-bracket-percentage parts of the quote code, I only left them in to make it clear I had seen the code in the content of a ASP.Net page. Apologies if this has led to any confusion)

Comment: Are you talking about the method chaining, or the `<%=` syntax?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's an example of [method chaining](http://www.factorypattern.com/method-chaining/)

Comment: is this similar to the concept of extension methods.

Comment: @Anirudha: no, an extension method is an implementation that extends an existing class.

Comment: Thanks for answer and for the link. There's some good examples in there which I've been able to build on.

Answer (score 6):

That's call a "fluent" API. Where each API returns an object (often `this`) on which you can call further methods.

This underlies LINQ when not using comprehension expressions.

Comment: Fluent API uses a similar technique, but this is not necessarily fluent API here. With the information given, it is just method chaining.

Comment: @MareInfinitus Accepted. But given the difference is largely in the eye of the beholder (large subjective element of "is this fluent to use?") many attempts at fluent interfaces can fail to be fluent by the perception of the user. Or to put it another way: method chaining is how you use an interface I find fluent to use.

Comment: Okay. Lets say: fluent interface is just a special case of method chaining.

Answer (score 1):

This syntax is used in asp.net to do some things in markup directly.

Normaly you use it to format strings or things like that to render them to the page.

The code has to return a string that will be palced in the html markup!

**edit**

Sorry, thought you are asking about the bracket syntax :P

Comment: Re: edit, the OP could have been asking that. The question has more than a little ambiguity.